# Why vibheeshana did not choose to be neutral?

Tags: ramayana, vibhishana

Vibheeshana loved his family . It was plausible for him to be neutral and not take sides with sri ram . why did he choose to end up in the camp of sri ram inspite of possiblity of being killed ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vibishana can't able to choose neutral because of boon by Brahma.

> Brahma then addressed Vibhishana, 'O my son, I am much pleased with
> thee! Ask any boon thou pleasest!' Thereupon, Vibhishana replied,
> '**Even in great danger, may I never swerve from the path of
> righteousness,** and though ignorant, may I, O adorable Sire, be
> illumined with the light of divine knowledge!' And Brahma replied, 'O
> scourge of thy enemies, as thy soul **inclines not to unrighteousness**
> although born in the Rakshasa race, I grant thee immortality!'
>
> [[SECTION CCLXXIII, Draupadi-harana Parva, Vana Parva, The Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03273.htm)
> ]

You can notice about the boon from Valmiki Ramayana also

> Thereat the virtuous Bibhishana spoke with joined hands, — 'O reverend
> one, since the spiritual preceptor of all creatures himself (is
> pleased) with me,— I (deem myself) as furnished with every perfection,
> even as the Moon is environed with rays. If thou wilt bestow on me a
> boon with pleasure, then, thou of excellent vows, hear of the boon
> that I would have. **May my mind remain fast fixed on righteousness,
> even when i shall happen to fall into high peril** ; and may I attain
> Brahma knowledge without any instructions ! And may every sense of
> mine sprung during the observance of particular modes of life, be in
> unison with righteousness, — so that I may practise the form of
> religion (in harmony with any particular mode of life !) O exceedingly
> noble one, this best of boons, is even what is sought for by me, for
> nothing in this world is incapable of being attained by those attached
> to righteous- ness.' Then the lord of creatures, being again
> delighted, spoke unto Bibhishana, — 'As thou art virtuous, so all this
> shall come to pass on thy behalf. **And inasmuch as in spite of thy
> having been born in the Rakshasa race, thy thoughts, O destroyer of
> enemies, do not originate in sin**, I confer on the immortality
>
> [[Uttarakandam, Valmiki Ramayana]](https://archive.org/details/TheRamayanaUttaraKandam/page/n47)

Since Ravana is unrighteousness in abducting Sita. Vibhishana can't be inclined towards Ravana. Hence he can't be neutral and selected righteousness Rama.