# Are there any asura that asked for a boon/wish and they didn't became evil?

Tags: puranas, asuras

There are many asura's that asked for wishes and became evil. Example ravan.

So are there asura's that were good even after there wish were full filled. Any examples of those asura who's boon itself was about power and strength.

Comment: What do you mean by asura here?

Comment: @hanugm tripurasur(Tarakaksha, Vidyunmāli and Kamalaksha), Bhasmasura and many more.

Comment: @hanugm these are some examples.

Comment: Will you consider the example of Vibishana?

Comment: @hanugm I have searched about Vibishana, According to wiki he was a raksha and not asura. Any way did he got any boon.

Comment: But Vibishana and Ravana are brothers, that's why I asked for meaning of asura you are referring to. Yeah, he got.

Comment: @hanugm was he good and what boon did he got

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34950

Comment: @hanugm OK, but can you answer it

Comment: okay, I will try to answer. I think there are some other examples. I will post whenever I'm free.  :)

Comment: @hanugm sorry to write this comment but Vibishana's boon itself was about being good. Can you give any examples of those asura who's boon itself was about power and strength.

Comment: okay, please update the question then.  I know some examples otherwise also... One is from Bhagavatam and one is from other scriptures...  There are such people...

Comment: @hanugm i have updated the question

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Karkati is one such example. She takes boon from Brahma and realizes later to become good and becomes Jivan muktha.

Her story is mentioned in [Part 3 - The Story of Karkaṭī](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/laghu-yoga-vasistha/d/doc209654.html) in `Utpatti-prakaraṇa` of Yoga-Vasistha

Initially, she performs an intensive tapas and asks Brahma for a boon as follows

> After she had passed thus a painful Tapas for
> 1,000 years, the Lotus-seated Brahmā appeared visibly before her. Are
> there any objects which cannot be acquired in this world even by the
> vicious through the performance of rare Tapas? With the arrival of
> Brahmā before her, she made obeisance to him mentally without stir
> ring from her spot and reflected thus: “**In order to assuage my
> ever-increasing fire, if I transform myself into the form of an
> iron-like Jīva-Sūcikā (living needle). I can enter into the bodies of
> all in the world and consume as much food as I require**.” Whilst these
> thoughts were revolving in her mind, Brahmā asked her the object of
> her wish. Karkaṭī replied thus “Oh Lord that favorest those, thy
> devotees who contemplate upon and praise thee. thy servant wishes to
> be come a Jīva-Sūcikā.”

After obtaining boon from Brahma, she utilizes her boon and harms others. But, afterwards, she realizes about evil in her and performs tapas again for Brahma with pure mind and finally gets liberation.

> So saying Brahmā vanished from view, whereupon this mountain-sized
> personage reduced herself to the size of a Jīva-Sūcikā and entered
> into the minds of the ferocious as well as the timid in order to make
> them perish. Having entered in the form of Vāyu within all Jīvas in
> earth and in Ākāśa, she fed upon all their lives in the form of Jīva
> Sūcikā and Vāyu-Sūcikā. Surfeited with such an enjoyment, she
> exclaimed “Whirling and making me despondent, my desires do make even
> the needle to wear away and making me giddy, do destroy me. Away with
> these desires of mine ! With a cruel heart. I have afflicted many
> lives in vain. **Therefore, I shall divest myself of all desires and
> perform Tapas in the Himalayas “So saying, she gave up all fluctuation
> of mind, devoid of any longing- for objects. Thus a thousand years
> passed, purifying her of the two-fold Karmas, (virtuous and sinful).**
> While thus, she was engaged in spiritual contemplation with an
> illuminated mind, free from all the pains of love and hatred and
> slighting this universe, the all-full Jñāna dawned in her mind and
> therefore Brahmā came voluntarily to her and imparted to her the
> following truths: (< Thou hast attained the Jīvanmukti state. Thy
> mind has been quite illumined; yet thou shalt be in thy old form of a
> Rākṣasa lady and sup port thyself on earth in the bodies of persons
> without Jñāna as well as the cruel and the base. Happiness thou shalt
> en joy thus.” With these blessings, Brahmā disappeared.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: This seems to be a good concrete example which addresses the question. I could not think of one, only tangential examples like Banasura, who received multiple boons from Shankarji. When his daughter Usha wanted to marry Krishna's grandson Aniruddha (who is amsh of Bhagavan Vishnu) of course there was a rather famous and dramatic battle, and according to Bhagavata Purana Krishna did not annihilate Banasura. Rather, Sri Krishna cut off all but two of Banasura's arms. I do not know if Banasura became less asuric after this.

Answer (score 4):

Vibhishana is an example. He asked for a boon that he should always be righteous and also obtain the light of divine knowledge from Brahma

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03273.htm

> Brahma then addressed Vibhishana, 'O my son, I am much pleased with thee! Ask any boon thou pleasest!' Thereupon, Vibhishana replied, '**Even in great danger, may I never swerve from the path of righteousness, and though ignorant, may I, O adorable Sire, be illumined with the light of divine knowledge**!'

Brahma was so pleased by him that he even bestowed upon him immortality.

> And Brahma replied, 'O scourge of thy enemies, as thy soul inclines not to unrighteousness although born in the Rakshasa race, **I grant thee immortality!'**